# In flutter how to change the size and font of textfield label

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to change the size and font of the textfield label

[image]

```
          TextField(
          controller: _dateController,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'Date',
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: that's what the ``labelStyle`` property is for!

Comment: thanks just started on flutter get used to navigating the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use labelStyle
like this

```
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: //..
    )
  ),
```